# How to do long-polling AJAX requests in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, long-polling

Does anyone know how to code up long-polling AJAX requests (for server PUSH notifications) in ASP.NET MVC?  Whenever I do it, it seems that only the last browser to open up a window gets the notifications.  As if IIS/ASP.NET were canceling the last request because it was hung or something.

Answer (score 33):

I recently wrote a [simple example of a Long Polling Chat Server](https://bitbucket.org/jacob4u2/mvcchatsite/src) using MVC 3 Async Controllers based on a [great article by Clay Lenhart](http://clay.lenharts.net/blog/2010/10/19/websockets-is-cool-but-what-can-you-do-today/)

You can use the [example on a AppHarbor deployment](http://mvcchatsite.apphb.com) I set up based on the source from the BitBucket project.

Also, more information available from my [blog post explaining the project](http://jacob4u2.blogspot.com/2011/04/mvc-3-long-polling-chat-example.html).