# Yield asynchronous results to a ASP PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, yield

I use an ajax call in a View to load data in a `PartialView` without blocking the UI.

```
$(function() {
     $.get( '@Url.Action("MyFunction", Model)', function( data ) {
                    $("#partialContainer").html(data);
                });
            }
```

The `Controller` code is really simple, `Task.Delay` will be replaced with another long running call to a web service:

```
public ActionResult MyFunction(MyFunctionModel model)
{
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
           Task.Delay(4000).Wait();    
      }
      return PartialView("PartialView", model);
}
```

What I would like to do is:

```
public ActionResult MyFunction(MyFunctionModel model)
{
          for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
               Task.Delay(4000).Wait();    
               yield return PartialView("PartialView", model);
           }
}
```

but I know that I cannot use the `yield` operator with an `ActionResult`.

Edit: The final idea is to show results every time something is adding up, let's say like a flight search engine does, without waiting for the full list of elements.

Comment: What benefits you expect from code you hope to get working?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov the final idea is to show results every time something is adding, let's say like any flight search engine does, without waiting for the full list of elements.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement [SingalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)
or [long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11431626/4868839).

If you need to update your UI in progressive way as you mentioned about flight results.