# How to loop an ajax call to continuously call a controller function?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an R code that updates the values stored in a text file. I have a controller function which returns a value stored in the text file. How do I repeatedly call the controller function to continuously display the updated values in the view?

Comment: You may call you ajax call periodically.
Look on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5052661/4093924).

Comment: @SreeLakshmi Agree to Vadim, I think its your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know before hand the number of times you want to loop you can simply put your ajax call in the javascript for loop and on ajax success keep updating your html view.

If you don't know then you would need implement [SingalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr) or [long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117421/how-to-do-long-polling-properly-in-mvc-3/11431626#11431626) to update your View progressively.

Comment: And the simplest solution is to use [settimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) function execute ajax after a specific internal.

Comment: You mean to use setInterval function right? I think JS loop is also simple once controller function finishes just exit the loop. Thoughts?

Comment: But it think it will conflict with asynchronous behavior of ajax call.

Comment: Okay. Coz I wanted to use same kind of same methodology for ajax calls. I will try with synchronous ajax calls and see how it works

Comment: Can you please help me out with a simple example on how to put ajax call in javascript for loop?

Answer (score 0):

**Ajax Function:**

```
function CallPageMethod(Url, ReqType, ContentType, CacheFlag, DataArray, SuccessMethod, FailureMethod) {
        $.ajax({
            url: Url,
            type: ReqType,
            contentType: ContentType,
            cache: CacheFlag,
            data: DataArray,
            success: function (resData) { return window[SuccessMethod](resData); },
            error: function (error) { return window[FailureMethod](error); }
        });
    }
```

**Call Ajax function:**

```
function GetDetails() {
    var serviceUrl = "/[Controller]/[ActionMethod]";
    var array = {};
    CallPageMethod(serviceUrl, PostReq, CTDefault, false, array, "Success", "Fail");
}

function Success(resData) {
}

function Fail(errData) {
}
```