# C# MVC notification system

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, notifications

I'm working on a C# MVC 4 application and I want to make a notification system much like facebook.

I thought about adding a notification in a table for each event, and then make AJAX calls to the database each 1 minute to retrieve notifications for the current user.

But I'm afraid it's too heavy.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342216/how-to-do-long-polling-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: I would take a look at signalR to abstract out the real time connection. It will save you a lot of effort over using jquery. Plus it will automagically use the most efficient notification method.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same thing as Aron, signalR is supppperrrr powerful and will do everything you need for notifications - http://www.asp.net/signalr

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet would be to go with SignalR. Its designed for the purpose of real time notification

[introduction-to-signalr](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)